DiscordAPI Missing Access when trying to remove members from a thread
I'm working on a feature for my bot that allows server moderators to remove all users from a given thread who have not sent a single message in that thread in the past 30 days. I have everything working so far, up to generating a list of ThreadMember objects representing the users I want to kick. However, when I call the remove() function on these objects, I'm met with:
DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access
     at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\DV Discord Bot\DVDiscordBot1\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:933:15)
     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
     at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\DV Discord Bot\DVDiscordBot1\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:712:14)
     at async REST.request (C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\DV Discord Bot\DVDiscordBot1\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1321:22)
     at async ThreadMemberManager.remove (C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\DV Discord Bot\DVDiscordBot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ThreadMemberManager.js:111:5)
     at async ThreadMember.remove (C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\DV Discord Bot\DVDiscordBot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ThreadMember.js:108:5) {        
   rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
   code: 50001,
   status: 403,
   method: 'DELETE',
   url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1181506798549741688/thread-members/114958895482404868',
   requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined } 
}

Here is how I have the feature currently implemented, if it helps. getThreadMsgsAfterDate is a helper function that repeatedly runs fetch commands to grab as many messages as necessary, to get around the 100 messages cap per fetch.
let threadMems = await thread.members.fetch();
let time = new Date();
time.setDate(time.getDate() - 30);
msgs = await getThreadMsgsAfterDate(thread, time);
let idsFound = new Set();
msgs.forEach((obj) => {
    idsFound.add(obj.author);
});
console.log(`Found ${idsFound.size} unique users in ${msgs.length} messages`);
let notInMostRecent = [];
threadMems.each(mem => {
    if (!idsFound.has(mem.id)) {
        notInMostRecent.push(mem);
    }
});
console.log(`${notInMostRecent.length}/${threadMems.size} thread members were not found in the most recent messages`);
notInMostRecent.forEach((mem) => {
    mem.remove(`Removed from thread: "${thread.name}" for inactivity. Please rejoin if you wish to continue using it.`);
});

I can confirm that everything works exactly as intended up to the mem.remove() call, which gives me the error I posted above. Solutions I have attempted so far, based on google searching I have done:

2FA is enabled on my (the bot owner's) Discord account
The bot has been given the Manage Threads permission by the server owner
The bot uses the GuildMembers gateway intent (and several others - let me know if you want the complete list)

Any advice is appreciated on additional things I can try. It's possible I may also have gotten one of the above attempts wrong as well - feel free to call me out if I have.

Does your bot have the send messages in threads permission? It needs that to edit threads, which includes removing members.
